# Visual Studio does not show errors in the code anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been using **Visual Studio (2017)** for quite a long time now, to program mostly in **C#**, for Unity games. Recently though, I noticed that **it was not displaying any errors in the code anymore**, or at least most of them. I initially started making some small tests, for example removing variables that were being used multiple times in the scripts. Visual Studio was not showing any errors, while when going back to Unity, it was showing all the correct errors in the console (as always). Instead, if I tried to remove a parenthese, it was, after a bit, showing errors all over the place. Again, it was really strange.

After one day, I was still testing, and I noticed that if I first opened Visual Studio, and then in "recent" I clicked on the the *.sln* file, that opened all the scripts for one Unity project, **it was immediately showing all the right errors**, like it had always done and how (I think) it should always do. I started looking for some differences between what I was seeing there, and what I was seeing when opening the *.cs* files (in the way that wasn't working):

- At the top, I wasn't seeing *"Debug"* and *"Any CPU"* how I was when it was working:

[image]
[image]

- Another thing was that, between the *"Project"* and the *"Debug"* buttons (at the top, that open the drop-down lists), I didn't have the *"Compile"* button.
- Also, under the the *"Debug"* drop-down many options like *"start debug"* were not available / disabled.
- At the top left, under the left-most script name, I have *"External files"* instead of *"Assembly-CSharp"*
- At the right of where there should be *"Debug"* and *"Any CPU"*, I have *"Connect"* instead of *"Start"* (Or something similar, my system's language is not english, these are translations)

Another (maybe less relevant) thing that has changed from before, when it was working:

- I have installed **Visual Studio 2019**, and uninstalled after a few minutes (I've always preferred Visual Studio 2017!).

Programming without seeing the errors realtime takes much more time, so I'd really like to fix this problem, if it is possible to do so. Is there anything that I have to activate? Did I accidentally press a combination of keys?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried repairing VS 2017?

Comment: @MihailDuchev Yes, I tried that as well, but still have the same problems.

Comment: What about `Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings`

Comment: Unfortunately that hadn't worked either.

Comment: When nothings helped, back when I used vs 2017, I close it, deleted the Component cache folder and everything worked fine. It is located in
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

If it doesn't help, there are other folders that you can try - https://www.matteopozzani.com/visual-studio-cache-cleanup/

Comment: I remember having a similar problem. Have you tried to rebuild the project using the SLN file and made sure it's still saved correctly to the unity project?

Comment: @MihailDuchev Thank you, but I didn't find that folder. Under "Microsoft\VisualStudio" I only have "Packages, "Setup", and "SetupWMI". I might then just try to uninstall it complitely and re-install it if I don't find other solutions!

Comment: It's in your user's AppData\Local\..., not in Program files

Comment: @MihailDuchev My bad! I tried that as well, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: sometimes it helps to remove the /bin /obj .vs catalogs and reopen/rebuild the solution

Comment: A few questions: does this reproduce for other solutions or just one? If it only happens for on solution, can you try installing VS2017 in a VM or another machine and check the behavior?

Comment: You can also try to delete the .suo file for this solution.

Comment: "You can also try to delete the .suo file for this solution" @AlexanderPope It worked!! Thank you very much, please write this as an answer so that I can award the 50 rep. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Deleting the .suo file might help when encountering erratic Visual Studio behavior.

The file contains user defined solution settings, including breakpoints, debug options,  bookmarks and may get corrupted or saved in an undesired state.

If you delete it, a new .suo file will be created once you reopen the solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: Works for Visual Studio 2022 too. The .suo is in the hidden .vs folder.

Comment: and where do you find this file?

Answer (score 2):

Just open the error list form `View -> Error List` or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + \ , E</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you but this didn't work either. The same errors that were not being displayed are not displayed in the error list. I edited my question, adding some information

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on the underline errors in the editor options in Visual Studio.

These options can be found here:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Help

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find "Editor Help" in the settings, but as I had written in my question, it did underline the errors, for example when I was removing a parenthese. But it doesn't show most of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also. For me it was caused by opening the project instead of the solution. When I opened the solution (.sln file), all the editor features started working.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem recently. What worked for me was Changing the `External Script Editor.` For this, open `Unity Editor` and go to `Edit > Preferences > External Tools > External Script Editor` Change it to `Microsoft Visual Studio.` Then run the script, it will detect the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a while and it had to do with my solution.
I went to my project, ran a code analysis on it, then I re-targeted it to an older version.

I have no idea why this worked, however it fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that didn't work either. Today I even tried reinstalling everything but it's still not working, I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the bin folder in the project directory, this will force the code to be recompiled.

Just make sure to save any .dll files in the bin folder that may have been added manually. You can see these in References in Solution Explorer, and add them back after.

Visual Studio will re-create the bin folder, don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in VS 2022 Preview version.

The solution was to check:
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Show error squiggles

[Options dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqmPG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting, type **Error Squiggles** in the search setting and then **enable** it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a file that was not included in the project.

After switching some branches a newly created file stopped being included in the project and was not being read for errors. I had to click "Show All Files" on solution explorer, right click the file and select "Include in project".

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to maybe try first if this just started happening to you...

My Error:

- 2022 VS: no compile time errors showing up in the Error List

My Solution:

- Close all open files/tabs, run: 'Clean Solution', close the solution, restart the solution, run: 'Rebuild Solution'.

My Result:

- Errors started showing up again.